# Why is the intercept not equal to the mean in my OLS with dummies?

Tags: regression, least-squares

I am regressing purchase value ("TOTAL") on different methods and sets.
Methods (A, B, C) and sets (1, 2, 3) are categorical, so R creates a dummy for each of these values. (Omitting one because otherwise we have perfect multicollinearity.)

My question: Shouldn't the intercept of the OLS be 107 (the mean of SET1 and A) instead of 111?

Means:

```
round(with(ORDERS, tapply(TOTAL, list(METHOD, SET), mean, na.rm=TRUE)), 0)
     SET1 SET2 SET3  
 A 107 187 132  
 B 123 195 138  
 C 109 127 116
```

OLS:

```
Call:
lm(formula = TOTAL ~ METHOD + SET, data = ORDERS)

Residuals:

    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-184.67  -82.92  -36.54   38.48 1327.23 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value             Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          111.481      3.580  31.136 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
PAYMENT_METHODB       11.911      3.570   3.337             0.000851 ***
PAYMENT_METHODC      -23.313      5.299  -4.399         0.0000109680 ***
COUNTRYSET2           68.725      3.401  20.207 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
COUNTRYSET3           18.317      3.391   5.402         0.0000000673 ***
```

Comment: Is all data complete?

Comment: I believe this is because the model-implied means may not be the same as the actual means.

Comment: center the covariates then run it

Comment: @IWS Yes, there are no N/As  
`> length(fitted(olsModel_P3_country))   
[1] 10000`

Comment: @MarkWhite You mean that it can be that the model mean is not the same as the sample mean? Wouldn't that imply that the model thinks the sample is not the best representation of the population?

Comment: @Ben The covariates are dummies, wouldn't they loose their interpretation if I centered them?

Comment: Add an interaction to your model and you will get 107 as intercept.

Comment: @Ben yes, the coefficients would lose some meaning after centering them. Try adding the interaction term, as @MichaelM suggests: `lm(TOTAL ~ METHOD*SET, ORDERS)`

Comment: Indeed, that solves it! @MichaelM Interesting... Thanks!